# Java Android - app works on 4.4 but doesn't work on 2.3.5

Tags: java, android, json

I'm doing a login in my android app, and it's working on 4.4 but on 2.3.5 it crashes because of `Log.d("PHP login response", json.toString())` and if i put it in comment the app will crash on `final String Loginresponse = json.getString("RESPONSE")`. Here's my code:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        final String loginEmail = inputLoginEmail.getText().toString();
        final String loginPassword = inputLoginPassword.getText().toString();

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", loginEmail));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", loginPassword));          

        // getting JSON Object
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_login_user, "POST", params);

        // check log cat for PHP response
        Log.d("PHP Login Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {

            final String Loginresponse = json.getString("RESPONSE");

            if(Loginresponse.equals("LOGIN_OK")){ // user successfully logged in

                pDialog.dismiss();

                //show the user profile
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PubsActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("session", loginEmail);
                startActivity(i);

                // closing this screen
                finish();

            } else { // failed to login user

                pDialog.dismiss();

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        if (Loginresponse.equalsIgnoreCase("LOGIN_MAIL_FORMAT_FAILED")){

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.invalidEmail), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        } else if (Loginresponse.equalsIgnoreCase("LOGIN_FAILED")) {

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.wrongLoginData), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        } else if (Loginresponse.equalsIgnoreCase("LOGIN_STATUS_NOK")) {

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.emailNotConfirmed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }
                    }
                });
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) { //error exception
           e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Here's the stacktrace:

```
02-22 14:28:31.570: E/Buffer Error(14816): Error converting result 

java.lang.NullPointerException
02-22 14:28:31.570: E/JSON Parser(14816): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
02-22 14:28:31.570: W/dalvikvm(14816): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2aac4560)
02-22 14:28:31.570: E/AndroidRuntime(14816): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
02-22 14:28:31.570: E/AndroidRuntime(14816): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
02-22 14:28:31.570: E/AndroidRuntime(14816):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
02-22 14:28:31.570: E/AndroidRuntime(14816):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
02-22 14:28:31.570: E/AndroidRuntime(14816):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
02-22 14:28:31.570: E/AndroidRuntime(14816):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
02-22 14:28:31.570: E/AndroidRuntime(14816):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
02-22 14:28:31.570: E/AndroidRuntime(14816):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
02-22 14:28:31.570: E/AndroidRuntime(14816):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
02-22 14:28:31.570: E/AndroidRuntime(14816):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
02-22 14:28:31.570: E/AndroidRuntime(14816): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-22 14:28:31.570: E/AndroidRuntime(14816):    at com.example.kroosky.MainScreenActivity$login.doInBackground(MainScreenActivity.java:181)
02-22 14:28:31.570: E/AndroidRuntime(14816):    at com.example.kroosky.MainScreenActivity$login.doInBackground(MainScreenActivity.java:1)
02-22 14:28:31.570: E/AndroidRuntime(14816):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
02-22 14:28:31.570: E/AndroidRuntime(14816):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
```

JSONParser:

```
package com.example.kroosky;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.X509HostnameVerifier;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;
import android.util.MalformedJsonException;

import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        Log.d("JASONParser","parse");

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
                Log.e("Response: ", String.valueOf(httpEntity));


            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "utf-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            Log.e("sb:",sb.toString());

            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

Comment: which line MainScreenActivity.java:181 ???

Comment: that line is Log.d("PHP Login response", json.toString())

Comment: `jsonParser` seems to be an instance of your custom class which seems to be returning null response. Can you post the class content so that we can see where is the problem?

Comment: I just don't understand why it's beautifully working on android 4.4 but on 2.3.5 it throws all that errors

Answer (score 1):

Your stacktrace shows that you've a `NullPointerException` exception. Did you verify that the JSON response is not null? Try catching the `NullPointerException` exception and the app won't crash.

Comment: Yes i know that JSON response isn't null because on android 4.4 it works and return me that responses

Answer (score 0):

JSONReader is not avilable for that. As far as I know there isn't even a compatibility lib. But luckily Android is open source: You would need to google for every file it uses, copy the code and include the file in your project (just as a normal new file).
You will probably need the files JsonReader.java, JsonScope.java, JsonToken.java, JsonWriter.java, MalformedJsonException.java, StringPool.java.

Edit: After reading through your post a second time I'm not too sure if that even is your problem (don't know how you got it running in first place), but feel free to test if it helps. I think I remember struggeling with something similar where it did help.

Comment: So I add the code of those files on a different class on my project source folder, is that ?

Comment: Just make a new folder in your project, maybe something like your.package.name.app.extern.JSON or something so you dont get confused. Create new files and paste the code. Then change your imports of the corresponding files to your new files. The reason behind this is that older Android versions just don't have the libraries you are trying to import, but I think Eclipse doesnt know that and doesn't throw the proper error.
Just look trough your code where you work with json and replace every json related file you are importing with a file in your project.